# Function call in for loop declaration

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, decrement

Could anybody explain me how this code is actually working?

when I run it, It gives me `52` as an output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Fun(void){ 
    static int x=7;
    return x--;
}

int main(void)
{
    for(Fun();Fun();Fun()) 
        cout<<Fun();

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You print without an spacing between different items. Even someone who's not a novice won't see the output as "obvious".

Comment: And this program will stop with  static int x= whatever;

Answer (score 1):

Every "regular" for loop has 3 parts :

- initialization
- condition
- iteration

On entering x is 7, initialization will return 7, decrement and go on with the condition where x is now 6. Upon condition it will return 6 (which is truthy), decrement and go on with the body where x is now 5. Upon printing, it will return 5, decrement and go on with the iteration where x is now 4.

Upon iteration it will return 4, decrement and go on with the condition where x is now 3. Upon condition it will return 3 (which is truthy), decrement and go on with the body where x is now 2. Upon printing it will return 2, decrement and go on with iteration where x is now 1.

Upon iteration it will return 1, decrement and go on with the condition where x is now 0. Upon condition it will return 0, which is falsy, and thus break out of the loop.

One of the important things to understand is that x is `static` and thus is part of the "state" of the function. It is initialized on first call and reused on each call.

Answer (score 1):

probably you better understand with this code, since you are doing `cout << Fun();` you see only the value at that time, you can see the return value at each phase with below code.

first *initialization* of `for` you get 7,

second *condition check* you get 6, since its non zero enters into loop.

inside loop call `Fun` which prints 5

then go to update part of `for` loop where we receive is 4

after that go to *condition check* it gives 3, since its non zero enter the loop

inside loop this time it will print 2

then go to update part of `for` which return 1

then go to *condition check* which gets 0, loop terminates.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Fun()
{ 
  static int x=7;
  return x--;
}

int main( )
{
    int x, y, z = 0;
    for( x = Fun(); y = Fun();z = Fun()) 
        cout<<"x = " <<x<<" y = "<<y<<" z = "<< z<<" and Fun ="<<Fun()<<endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After each call of the function Fun the static variable x is decremented. The function returns the value of the variable x before decrementing.

So in this for loop

```
for(Fun();Fun();Fun()) 
  cout<<Fun();
```

Before the body of the loop gets the control the function Fun was called two times

```
for(Fun();Fun();Fun()) 
     1     2
```

So after these calls the value of the variable x is equal to 5. This value is outputted in the statement

```
  cout<<Fun();
```

and after the call of the function used in this statement the value of x becomes equal to 4.

Then again the function Fun was called two times

```
for(Fun();Fun();Fun()) 
           2     1
```

So the value of the x becomes equal to 2. This value is outputted in the statement

```
  cout<<Fun();
```

And after the call of the function in this statement the value of x is equal to 1. Then in the first call of Fun

```
for(Fun();Fun();Fun()) 
           2     1
```

the value of x becomes equal to 0. This value is returned by the second call of the function. So the condition evaluates to boolean false.

Thus the loop outputted two numbers 5 and 2. The result value of the static variable x is -1. (0 was returned in the last call of Fun and after that the variable x was decremented)

Answer (score 0):

To understand, you can "unroll" the loop:

```
int Fun()
{ 
  static int x = 7;
  return x--;
}

int main()
{
  Fun();                // x is 6
  if (!Fun()) return 0; // x is 5
  std::cout << Fun();   // prints 5, x is 4
  Fun();                // x is 3
  if (!Fun()) return 0; // x is 2
  std::cout << Fun();   // prints 2, x is 1
  Fun();                // x is 0
  if (!Fun()) return 0; // end
}
```

Note that `Fun()` returns a value which equals `x+1`.